# Model bind doesn't work in Asp.net Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net, bind, mode

Following this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0 :

```
[Bind] attribute
Can be applied to a class or a method parameter. Specifies which properties of a model should be included in model binding.

In the following example, only the specified properties of the Instructor model are bound when any handler or action method is called:

C#

Copy
[Bind("LastName,FirstMidName,HireDate")]
public class Instructor
In the following example, only the specified properties of the Instructor model are bound when the OnPost method is called:

C#

Copy
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult OnPost([Bind("LastName,FirstMidName,HireDate")] Instructor instructor)
The [Bind] attribute can be used to protect against overposting in create scenarios. It doesn't work well in edit scenarios because excluded properties are set to null or a default value instead of being left unchanged.
```

I have a model defined as

```
public class Family
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

When I used this in Web Api controllers, I expected the input faimly model only have the name property but ignore the address property (null or empty). 
PostMan Json Body:

```
 {
"Name": "Faimly1",
"Address":"Address1"
 }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Family>> PostFamily([FromBody][Bind("Name")] Family family)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(family.Name); // Expect the string "Family1".
        Console.WriteLine(family.Address); // Should be empty even I have passed a string value.
    }
```

When I use Postman to test the action I still get the Address value.
What should I do? I tested this both in asp.net core 3.0 and asp.net core 2.1 and get the same result.

Or this Bind only works with tag helper?

Comment: maybe try **[Bind(Include = "Name")]** instead of just **[Bind("Name")]** , see if it helps.

Comment: Ｉ use Bind(include:"Name"), still not work.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of BindAttribute, you can try to use [JsonIgnoreAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=netcore-3.0) in your model class:

```
public class Family
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That is a pretty poor hack. What if the Web API is responding to XML or some other format besides JSON?

Comment: This is not a resolution. JsonIgnore will break the content if I convert it to json string and then save to a file. I would prefer using ViewModel other than JsonJgnore. But I just wondered why bind not work anymore?